# Should I free allocated memory when I exit?

Tags: c, terminal

I am writing a c terminal program that runs until the user terminates it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. Think something like `ping` or `top`.

My program allocates to the heap but starts no other threads or processes. Should I be handling SIGINT and freeing any allocated memory before exit or is leaving it to the OS better practice?

Comment: As soon as your program exits any memory it has allocated will be returned to the OS anyway, but it is still good practice to free your allocated memory yourself.

Comment: You would need all allocated memory pointers to be global for a handler to be able `free` them, which is poor program design. In the normal flow you would need to be scrupulous in setting any `free`d pointer to `NULL` - as well as the problem of blocking the signal should it occur between you `free`ing memory in the usual course of the program, and setting its pointer to `NULL`.

Comment: I would not necessarily have to free the memory in the handler, for example one could just set a flag in the handler to stop the main loop and free the memory after the loop exits. But yes, it would be a considerable amount of effort for questionable gain, hence the question.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes given your context, which is a normal exit situation. In an abnormal exit situation, then the short answer is absolutely no.

If you are concerned that your program is leaking memory during its execution, which is a bad thing in the sense that it slows your program execution, then you can keep track of the memory that you allocate and then free it before you exit. Then you can run your program with valgrind and if valgrind complains about blocks that weren't free'd, then you will know you have some type of leak. The location of the allocation will help you know if the leak is of any importance.

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: @jayjay That's probably because I was being passive aggressive when I wrote "If you are ...". You should be concerned and the easy way to prove you have no leaks is to free your freeable memory when you exit normally (your context) and let valgrind do the hard work.

Comment: @jayjay Odd, in your "stop the main loop" comment you say precisely what I prescribe. Then when valgrind gets control it will say which memory blocks are `lost` and where those blocks were allocated. It's a beautiful thing.

Comment: I am simply not interested in Valgrind. Its a great tool, but not the focus of this question. In fact not mentioned anywhere in the question, or any of my comments.

Comment: @jayjay True you didn't mention valgrind but you did mention freeing memory and proving that you are freeing all of your memory requires a "great tool".

Comment: I am a great tool, I require no other.

Answer (score 0):

If you exit anyway, you don't need to release any resources.  The OS will take care of it just fine, and there is no benefit in doing it manually.

Note that free() is not [async-safe](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html), so you would definitely have to do the actual freeing in the main thread, and not in the handler.  But don't do that, unless you want to do other things than exit().

Use SIGINT handlers for things like resetting the terminal (e.g. with ncurses), or saving critical state.

Comment: Resources should always be released, even if the OS can reclaim them automatically. Running valgrind on a program that does not release its resources can yield false positive and makes it harder to track bug in production.

Comment: I don't think it is necessary to have valgrind provide accurate reporting after SIGINT, but your requirements may be different.

Comment: Not all resources are created equal... If you've opened a file for writing and don't properly close it - it will get truncated. This is just one example for illustration purposes

Comment: exit() will flush the buffers of IO streams.  There are other examples though (lock/pid files, semaphores, named pipes), but none of them were called out in the original question.